# Tailwind css con modificador (onloadpage:)

Tags: css, tailwind

mi idea es la siguiente, se puede asignar un modificador de clase como "hover" o "selected", que sea en estado de carga del elemento, es decir cuando se carga la pagina?

Los modificadores a los que me refiero es
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Una solución que hay es utilizando javascript como aqui en el ejemplo tres de la síguente página
https://devdojo.com/tnylea/animating-tailwind-transitions-on-page-load

La idea es que sea un modificador onload: u otra palabra pero que sea sencillo, y no agregar el código que presenta en dicho ejemplo, alguna idea?